# Formula Generation In C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, software-design

I have a scenario where I need to calculate Overtime for an employee. But formula that suppose to use will required to be dynamic. Columns I have in database are EmpId int, OTHrs float, Salary int, WorkingDays int, WorkingHrsPerDay int.
E.g., One customer ask to use formula as OTAmount = (Salary/30/8) * OTHrs
While other customer ask to use formula as OTAmount = ((Salary/30/8) * OTHrs)*1.5

Now, I am going to write a stored procedure that calculate overtime for every employee. Please help, in what format should we take Overtime Rate from UI. So it could be later used for Overtime Amount Calculation and once calculated and saved in database, will be displayed on reports.

Comment: 1. hi, best way to solve this is, like you said, store the formula somewhere in the database, it's easier to you if someday, the formula need to be changed tho. 2. The user need to be careful before write down the formula, so it's the user's responsibility. 3. There are many ways, but this is the best approach

Comment: 2. execute the formula string the user enters against DB to simulate real use (maybe against a record inserted in transaction that is rollbacked imediately, or against a record just for this purpose of testing) and see if it returns a numeric result, if it does, it has correct syntax

Comment: Do you have to run a stored procedure to do the calculation, or can you load the data and run it in a normal C# process?

Comment: 2: You could do basic checks like if every starting bracket has a ending bracket, all the syntax stuff. But its impossible to find out, if the formula makes sense, I guess. And please keep things like SQL Injection in mind

Comment: @Enigmativity I need to finally show OTAmount on UI against each employee, and all calculations that I am going to perform is planned to do in Stored Procedure, that is why I go this way.

Comment: I would recommend you to not insert it into your stored procedure though, it can be very dangerous. Maybe try to get all the data needed and do it client-sided?

Comment: @Jannik Can't do it on client side, there are lot of fields (like late deduction, allowance calculation, etc.). Thanks for the advice though.

Comment: If you want to ensure that the formula was correctly written, you can use the polish algorithm in order to validate the expression entered.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation

Comment: @farhaniqbal - I don't know why the sheer number of fields means that you can't do it client-side?

Comment: @Enigmativity There are 400 EmpId and I need to calculate OTAmount, All kind of allowances, deductions, Lates, and finally show data on report. Doing this on client side wasn't looked the correct thing (as i finally need to store results in database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to store the whole formula. Just import values as parameters.

Add another column to store OT Rate. Set OT rate as 1 to customer 1 and set OT rate as 1.5 to customer 2.

Then you can use generalized formula as

```
OTAmount = ((Salary/WorkingDays/WorkingHrsPerDay) * OTHrs)*OTRate
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd have a limited number of formulae, each with a specific Id/Code. You can then add a column to your spreadsheet with the formula ID. In the code, simply add a Dictionary or switch statement, and it will use the formula you want for each specific row.